# window is not defined in opentok-text-chat node module

Tags: node.js, opentok

I am working in node js. I installed opentok-text-chat using npm. Then I started using node server.js, it returns following error:

```
E:\simerjit\dawai\node_modules\opentok-text-chat\dist\opentok-text-chat.js:14
    window.jQuery = $;
    ^

ReferenceError: window is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\simerjit\dawai\node_modules\opentok-text-chat\dist
\opentok-text-chat.js:14:5)
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\simerjit\dawai\node_modules\opentok-text-chat\dist
\opentok-text-chat.js:608:3)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\simerjit\dawai\server\routes.js:28:32)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The opentok-text-chat library is a client-side library, it can help you add text chat functionality to your opentok application.

It is not a server-side node library, therefore it causes this error when it tries to access the window object which doesn't exist in node.

You can check out the library documentation quick start here https://github.com/opentok/accelerator-textchat-js#quick-start

or see one of the example applications here
https://github.com/opentok/accelerator-sample-apps-js

Comment: A new error : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'property' of undefined
    at _validateOptions (opentok-text-chat.js:463)
    at new TextChatAccPack (opentok-text-chat.js:561)

Calling Without a module bundler

Comment: The line at 463 is `_session = _.property('session')(options);` Therefore the undefined variable is `_` which is the variable used for underscorejs. You need to add all of the project dependencies as here : https://github.com/opentok/accelerator-textchat-js#without-a-module-bundler

Comment: Fixed this issue, Is there a way to add video mute button as there is audio mute option? @maikthomas

Comment: Yes, the sample applications have a button for toggling video as well as muting audio. They are located in this github repository https://github.com/opentok/accelerator-sample-apps-js